# What the return statement would do inside the router.post in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was going through my organisations code where I found a code similar to below

```
router.post('/listings', async (req, res) => {
    //some thing related to req
    return res.status(200).json({
        code: 200,

    })
})
```

Where exactly the return statement is received since this api will be called directly by user. Is this a right way to do it?
Moreover what would be returned exactly since response is passed through res and not return.

Comment: `return` returns the flow of execution to the calling function. You haven't tagged this with any particular framework or library so we can only guess what `router.post` expects your function to return.

Comment: Anyone familiar with nodejs can actually tell that it is related to express. Man router is itself a middleware. Everyone uses these terms in nodejs. What do you expect should I list the config file also from next code.

Comment: How about "express", if that is the library you're using? Node is not express, and express is not Node.

Comment: @meagar don't just comment anything for the sake of commenting. Anyone can easily tell it is for express.

Comment: We have tags for a reason. You're required to tag the question with the relevant tags for it to be on-topic here. "Anybody can tell" or "everybody knows" are not useful terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question,

The route handlers are just middlewares inside express architecture, and `res.json({})` just passes data to the default middleware, so the return statement is used to stop the execution if there are other blocks of code below:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (something) {
     return res.json({ message: "A thing" });
  }

  res.json({ message: "Other thing" });
});
```

Comment: So, basically the return statement has no further effect and is just used to stop the execution.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. But don't take my word for it, for further reading I highly recommend the following: 1 - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html  2 - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html  3 - http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html